# CE String outputting global variable tag minus "{ }"

Tags: parse-order, ce-image, global-variables

I've got a page behind a login that I have various member groups set up for.

Depending on the member group, I want the link in the Downloads section to go to a different page: e.g. Contractors member group will go to /downloads/contractors, Students member group will go to  /downloads/students etc.

When I use my global variable for {group_title} in my page, it outputs "Contractors".  Ideally it should output "contractors" in my link because if a member group has more than one word my URL isn't valid.

I tried wrapping {group_title} in CE String but it just outputs "group_title" into my HTML without the braces.

Here's my code:

{exp:ce_str:ing url_title}{group_title}{/exp:ce_str:ing}

Answer (score 0):

This is because user-defined global variabes are parsed *after* plugin and module tags. ([See parse order.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages)) So you're literally passing `{group_title}` to CE String.

Try setting `{group_title}` via a [preload_replace](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html) variable instead, as those are processed just before plugin tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Derek but no joy. Am I right in thinking that it's too early in the parse order to output what I want from the tags now. It's just printing out 'group_title' inside my link. 

{preload_replace:member_group="{group_title}"}

    <nav class="nav--sidebar">
       <ul class="nav__list">
  {if logged_in}
        <li>
          <a href="{site_url}member/downloads/{exp:ce_str:ing url_title}{member_group}{/exp:ce_str:ing}">{group_title} Downloads</a>
        </li>  
  <li>
          <a href="{path='logout'}">Log Out</a>
        </li>
     {/if}

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to *set* group title in a `preload_replace` variable, i.e. `{preload_replace:group_title="Contractors"}`. How exactly you'd setup the logic to do this will depend on how exactly you're determining what that value should be.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions Derek. I was over thinking this. A simple if check around the couple of headings & links that I want to change will suffice. It might work out at maybe 4 lines of code more but at least it's a simple solution to something that's not even a massive problem.